# Youtube iframe not embedding in my website?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

i want to embed youtube video through "iframe" but Youtube is ban in my country, recommend me how to embed video on my website!

[1]: here is image attached that shows youtube is not accessible in my country

Answer (score 0):

The video will be embedded, even if you can't see it.

If you want to see it, you will need to setup VPN and it will send your internet traffic over a secure VPN tunnel, so you can see the Youtube video and verify the video works.